# How do you create a new user with access to /var/www/html with ssh?

Tags: ssh, permissions, users

I Need new sftp login details for developers but that is restricted to `/var/www/html/` using `ssh`. They have to be able to edit and save files, also when the user makes changes I don't want the group changing to the users group once they make changes, if that makes sense.

Comment: what system is it?

Comment: Centos 6.3, Zend community server on Rackspace Cloud if that's any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ACLs here.

Create your user with useradd. Then grant him the correct permission on `/var/www/html`

```
#> setfacl -m u:myuser:rwx /var/www/html
```

Use -R option, to modify all the subdirectories

```
#> setfacl -R -m u:myuser:rwx /var/www/html
```

Verify that it worked by using `getfacl`

```
#> getfacl /var/www/html
```

Also for your group name request, you might want to flag the html directory with the setgid flag `chmod +s /var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user with

```
 useradd -D /var/www/html xyz
```

so /var/www/html will be the default home directory for user xyz , but if you are running
apache and /var/www/htmlis home directory than this solution is not gonna work.

Instead you should create a user with any other home directory and restrict user with SUDO 
access for APACHE.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use httpd-itk from epel to run each site by own user. And proftpd (mod_sftp) to gain access to the web root.